# Viewport always centralized on a bigger background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport

It is possible to make viewport behave like this with css and/or javascript/jQuery:

[image]

Currently, I'm using the css below to make the background cover the whole viewport:

```
#background {    
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  top:0; left:0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  -moz-background-size: cover !important;
  -o-background-size: cover !important;
  background-size: cover !important;    
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

but that's not what I really need. Using it that way, on low screen resolutions the background image will distort and looks real bad.

**EDIT**
Just to be clear, I'm not concerned about mobile users. That's not the purpose of the system  I'm working at at first. It will be a desktop system.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
#background {
    background: url('image/myimage.jpg') center center;
}
```

or

```
body {
    background: url('image/myimage.jpg') center center;
}
```

If you can set your back ground at the body level then there is no need for a #background element.

But setting the image using CSS will not scale the image and the  "center center" will center the image vertically and horizontally.

Regardless of the image size this will center it. However, you will have to always provide an image larger than the largest resolution you support to get the "over-scan" style you have represented.

However, if you wanted to stretch the background image you can do the following. It does require the use of javascript and the jQuery library.

HTML:

```
<div id="divBackWrapper">
    <div id="divBackCenter">
        <img src="http://www.abc.net.au/radionational/image/4220698-3x2-700x467.jpg" width="700" height="467" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    padding:0; margin:0;
}

#divBackWrapper, #divBackCenter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#divBackCenter {
    overflow: visible;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#divBackWrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* change to auto to allow width set by height, one must always be 100% */
    height: auto; /* change to 100% to allow height stretching */
    min-width: 700px;
    min-height: 467px;
    top: -50%; /* half height */
    left: -50%; /* half width */

}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {

        var $window = $(window);
        var $img = $("#divBackCenter img");

        if ( $img.width() <= $window.width() ) {
            $("#divBackCenter").removeAttr("style");
            $("#divBackCenter img").removeAttr("style");
            return;
        } else {
            var css = {};
            css.top = -($img.height() - $window.height()) / 2;
            css.left = -($img.width() - $window.width()) / 2;

            $("#divBackCenter").css({top:0,left:0});
            $("#divBackCenter img").css(css);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of your answer. The only problem I see with this approach is the scale. I need to find a solution where if the viewport resolution is bigger than the background, it fits automatically. I think I'll have to treat this with jQuery or JS.

Comment: Will the background image size always be known?

Comment: Yes, always 1920x1080 as in the example. Actually, i don't think I'll have problems with screen resolutions bigger than the background (thinking on the scope of my clients), but it could happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jquery backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) a couple of times to get the background stretching stuff done easily. I know it also does what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that pluggin and it seems to be really helpfull.

Comment: great. If you think it was helpful please mark this answer as the correct one so other people know it is helpful.

Comment: Sure. Just finishing to test it.